Generalized Clairaut Equation
I read about Clairaut's Generalized ODEs (from an exercise sheet) which have the following form:
$$f(xy'-y)=g(y')$$
I have shown that:
$$y''[xf'(xy'-y)-g'(y')]=0$$
From there I can easily show that the following family of functions:
$$y(x)=Ax+B$$
satisfy this ODE.
But I do not know how to find a solution for the equation:
$$xf'(xy'-y)-g'(y')$$
Is there a general way/method for finding solutions to this type of equations?

Notice that not all functions of the family $y=Ax+B$ are solutions to the original ODE. The coefficients $A$ and $B$ must satisfy the relation $f(-B)=g(A)$.

Not a full answer but too long for a comment:
Suppose $y(x)$ is a solution satisfying the initial condition $y_0 = y(x_0)$, and denote
$$\tilde y := y - x y' \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad \tilde y_0 := y_0 - x_0 y'(x_0) .$$
For convention's sake replace $f(u)$ with $f(-u)$.

If $f'(\tilde y_0) \neq 0$, there is an interval $U \ni \tilde y_0$ on which $f'\vert_U$ vanishes nowhere, and there we can rewrite the equation in the form of Clairaut's (original) equation,
$$y - x y' = (f\vert_U^{-1} \circ g)(y')$$
and so (locally) proceed as usual.

If $f'(\tilde y_0) = 0$, on the other hand, substituting the initial condition $y(x_0) = y_0$ in the equation
$$x f'(y - x y') - g'(y')$$
gives that
$$g'(y'(x_0)) = 0,$$
giving a necessary condition on the initial condition for the existence of a solution.


So, for example, if $f$ is constant and $g$ has nonvanishing derivative, there is no solution $y(x)$ of $$x f'(y - x y') - g'(y') = 0$$ for any initial condition, hence in that case the only solutions $y(x)$ of the generalized Clairaut equation are the linear ones.
One might be able to say more using Legendre transformations (see the above link).
